# Javascript works in jsfiddle but not on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm really a Javascript beginner and just started with Jquery mobile.

My problem is that I have a working example in jsfiddle but when I copy it to my page it is not working anymore.
In jsfiddle it is only working when I choose the "onLoad" option in the menu. So I guess I placed the script wrong or I have to call it again when the page is loaded.

I wrapped the function with `$(document).ready(function() { });` and `$(function(){});` because I read this would start the script when the site has been loaded.

Is there method I have to use in Jquery Mobile to wrap my code? Or do I make an error in Javascript basics?

Thanks a lot,
Sven

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FtXWA/

And this is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascipt">
    $(function(){
        $("#slider").bind("change", function(event, ui) {
            alert("test");
        });
    });
</script>
</head> 
<body>

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">    
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" />
        </div>    
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but you might find that `$(window).load(` (instead of `$(document).ready(` works.

Comment: Maybe, but my guess is that it's a problem with jquery and the device.  Note the letters "rc" in the name of the jquery file.  "Release candidate" means "maybe it works, maybe it doesn't."  My next line of investigation would be hard-coding an onclick handler for #slider and see if that works.  If it does, then it seems to indicate that jquery isn't fully working on your device.  Maybe it doesn't play well with the bind method, which relies on certain underlying DOM methods like addEventListener, and maybe  your device doesn't support those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile you shouldn't use `$(document).ready()`.

Try to bind pagecreate instead:

```
$('#pageID').live('pagecreate', function(){ /*code*/ });
```

This function will trigger when `#pageID` has finnished loading and has been enhanced by jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks ok. might try to comment out the function wrapper?

```
$(function(){
    $("#slider").bind("change", function(event, ui) {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

To this

```
//$(function(){
    $("#slider").bind("change", function(event, ui) {
        alert("test");
    });
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

Naning is correct see this post for more details

http://operationmobile.com/using-jquery-mobile-remember-to-use-pagecreate-instead-of-document-ready/